# how to load a source at start in vimrc

Tags: vim, snipmate

I was not able to get snipMate to work with gvim and then found that there is an existing [issue](http://code.google.com/p/snipmate/issues/detail?id=66).  the solution seems to be to run the following command after opening vim
 `source ~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim`

To save me from the pain of remembering to run that every time I open vim, I tried adding that same command to my startup settings (~/.vimrc)..however that does not seem to work.

Is there another way to load this at the time when I start vim?

Comment: Are you sure vim is reading your `~/.vimrc` file? Try `~/_vimrc`, I've seen that name a lot when Windows systems are involved.

Comment: @sarnold On windows vim reads both `~/.vimrc` and `~/_vimrc`. The background for using the second name is that explorer.exe fobids user to create filenames starting with dot.

Comment: @ZyX, ah! Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your .vimrc:

```
:so ~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the appropriate file type without the defined type snipmate not know how to complete eg.

```
:set ft=python
```